# java.sql.ResultSet getBigDecimal when it's null

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to read from a resultSet a BigDecimal which is null

```
bean.setAuthorizedAmount(res.getBigDecimal(columnIndex++));
```

and it's giving the following exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation
```

Can you suggest the simplest code that could simply map on BigDecimal, whether the column is null or not, for instance as you can do for String?

Hope I was clear enough, thanks in advance.

Comment: The column datatype may be different  in this case.

Comment: What should be returned in case the column value in the database is NULL? If you want to return BigDecimal.ZERO you could for example amend the SQL statement to return `NVL(column, '0')`.

Comment: What's the column data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happen when your column data can not be converted to the `BigDecimal` or any type you are looking for. I think you have started `columnIndex` from `0` in that case you won't be able to get the exact column you want. It says java is unable to convert data to `BigDecimal` from the column value.

**EDIT :**

As stated by [`Luiggi Mendoza`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065197/luiggi-mendoza) in comment, it would be much better to use column name instead of column index to avoid such problems and yes it increases the readability as well.

Comment: So, as best practice, it's better to retrieve the colums by name rather than by index.

Comment: I solved retrieving columns by name, it returns null when column is null. Thanks.